# how to set databse data in list adapter and select a particluar item of that list after set adapter

Tags: android, database, sqlite, comments, listadapter

I want to call data from database and set it on list adapter. then wish to select a particular item and display its corresponding info.
 till now  i am able to call data and set List adapter. now how to  select a particular item from list.

i tried converting  data from Comment to string but that don't work.

```
 List<Comment> values = datasource.getAllComments();

Array Adapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the OnClickListener of the ListView do something like this

```
LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            myDialog = new Dialog(Dealer_data.this);
            myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.detail_dealer);
            myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            myDialog.setTitle("Dealer Details");
            myDialog.setCancelable(true);

            TextView t1;
            t1 = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            int a=1;
            int add_pos= position+a;
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position after add= "+add_pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            deal_id=""+add_pos;
            pos = new ArrayList<String>();
            Cursor col =dbCarHelper.getdealer(deal_id);
            for (col.moveToFirst(); !col.isAfterLast(); col.moveToNext()) {
                // The Cursor is now set to the right position
                pos.add(col.getString(0));
                pos.add(col.getString(1));
                pos.add(col.getString(2));
                pos.add(col.getString(3));
                pos.add(col.getString(4));
                pos.add(col.getString(5));
                pos.add(col.getString(6));
                pos.add(col.getString(7));
                pos.add(col.getString(8));
                pos.add(col.getString(9));
            //  pos.add(col.getString(10));
            }

            full_detail = "Car Make : " + pos.get(0) + "\nState : " + pos.get(1)
                    + " \nCity : " + pos.get(2) + "\nCompany Name : " + pos.get(3)
                    + "\nCompany Address : " + pos.get(4) + "\nPhone : " + pos.get(5)
                    + "\nMobile : " + pos.get(6) + "\nFax : " + pos.get(7)
                    + "\nEmail : " + pos.get(8) + "\nWebsite : " + pos.get(9);
            t1.setText(full_detail);
            myDialog.show();

        }
    });
```